# populating html elements with json data through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working on a piece of code in which i add data from a json document to my html through jquery. i am new to jquery and stuck here.

https://jsfiddle.net/to53xxbd/

this the html

```
 <ul id="list">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
```

this is the script

```
var json = [
  {
    "_id": "5771ff92e0a1dea908b82d9a",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff92d906e7541ed51198",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff925a7ed5d7558e3fbc",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff9201669663584e0f25",
    "index": 3
  }
]

function myfunction(json)
{
        $.each(json,function(
            $(this).innerhtml= json.index;
    ));
}
$(document),ready(function(){
    $("#list li").myfunction(json);
});
```

this is what i have tried.
Is this method correct? or are there any different methods to do the same easily.

Comment: Check console for *syntax errors*. Also you are mixing jQuery and Javascript properties.

Comment: you have `$().myfunction` but `myfunction` is not defined as a jQuery plugin

Comment: you seriously need to learn jquery or javascript first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a solution using jQuery.map()

HTML code

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

and then your Javascript file:

```
var json = [
  {
    "_id": "5771ff92e0a1dea908b82d9a",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff92d906e7541ed51198",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff925a7ed5d7558e3fbc",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff9201669663584e0f25",
    "index": 4
  }
]

$(function(){
var data = [];

$(json).map(function(i, item) {
   data.push('<li>'+item.index+'</li>');
   });
   $('#list').append(data);
})
```

and a JSfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/to53xxbd/

This way you're only manipulating the DOM only once appending the complete array to the DOM.

Best Regards,

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like this
Html

```
<ul>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var json = [
  {
    "_id": "5771ff92e0a1dea908b82d9a",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff92d906e7541ed51198",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff925a7ed5d7558e3fbc",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff9201669663584e0f25",
    "index": 3
  }
]

$(function(){
   for(i=0;i<json.length;i++){
      $("ul").append("<li>"+json[i].index+"</li>")
    }
})
```

Please let me know if it helps

Comment: yes this does the work , but cant we just insert html into li tags through innerhtml method so that i dont have to add new elements but rather change the value of existing elements

Comment: Hey bro just imagine a scenario where  your <li> tags length is more than those of your SO CALLED json list?  Hope you got the point.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/qwo32DO0u45Uhbduq5Ry?p=preview

HTML

```
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

javascript

```
var json = [
  {
    "_id": "5771ff92e0a1dea908b82d9a",
    "index": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff92d906e7541ed51198",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff925a7ed5d7558e3fbc",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "5771ff9201669663584e0f25",
    "index": 3
  }
]



$(function(){
var data = [];

$.each(json, function(i, item) {
  alert(i);
   data.push('<li>'+item.index+'</li>');

   });
   $('#list').append(data.join(''));
})
```